# Changing IE Home Page through GPO?

Tags: windows, group-policy, internet, internet-explorer

Seems this should be simple, but I'm unable to find the combination of GPO options to default the home page so that the user can't change it, but to let them add any of their own home pages to the list of tabs?

Thanks.

Comment: Greg I agree entirely, however if you look at my previous questions I'd argue they are mostly opinion based, there isn't a "right" answer.  Have to admit I hadn't noticed the vote arrows though so hands up on that one :)

Comment: Then you aren't asking the right types of questions for SF.  You should ask questions that can actually be answered.  For more information you can visit the FAQ:  http://serverfault.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality to do what you're looking for that I'm aware of. The Internet Explorer Group Policy Client Side Extension (CSE) can't do what you're talking about, and I don't believe Internet Explorer itself has functionality to all for a "forced" home page but still allowing the user to add addt'l home pages to open on new tabs.

If you feel strongly about it put in a feature request to Microsoft (or hire somebody to add the feature to a Free browser and start using that... >smile<).

Comment: Thanks Evan, you've confirmed what I'd already been led to believe - know when you think "You must be able to do it, it's such an obvious thing to want to do"... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Realizing this is a stale thread and I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to by "but to let them add any of their own home pages to the list of tabs?"
But this setting for a "default," unchangeable home page to Sharepoint worked well for us.  Users can still add favorites to the IE bar.

User Configuration \
Policies \
Windows Settings \
Internet Explorer Maintenance \
URLS/Important URLs ---> Home Page URL

Comment: Without a significant degree of more detail I don't see how this answers the original poster's question.

Comment: If the question is about making IE start with the same home page every time for every user, but still allowing them to customize tabs and favorite options, the above GPO does the trick.  Try it, you might like it.  :)

Comment: @westbadger it's never a stale thread as long as IE exists.

Answer (score 2):

This a partial answer in that you can not stop them editing it.

GroupPolicy

```
User Configuration
  Windows Settings
    Internet Explorer URL's
      Homepage URL = http://bla.com
```

You may need to add some policy packs if this is not available to you.  We first did this on a 2003 domain and now a 2008 domain.

Comment: I don't mind if they can change/edit it so long as when the policy refreshes/they logoff and on, the default tab is our Intranet, it's just we have no problem with them setting any additional homepage tabs to whatever they want.

Comment: It is a user policy so it should reset the homepage url ever time they log in.